# Dojo attach point / byId returns undefined

Tags: dojo, undefined, getelementbyid

I made a template and there is a `<select dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" dojoAttachPoint="selectPageNumber" id="selectPageNumber">`tag with id and dojoAttachPoint be "selectPageNumber". I want to populate it with options upon create so I add some code to the postCreate function:

```
var select = dijit.byId("selectPageNumber");
```

or

```
var select = this.selectPageNumber;
```

but I always have `select` being undefined.
What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:**
The problem with  element has been solved spontaneously and I didn't got the solution. I used neither `dojo.addOnLoad` nor `widgetsInTemplate : true`, it just started to work. But I have found the same problem again: when I added another  tag I can't get it!
HTML:

```
<select class="ctrl2" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" dojoAttachPoint="selectPageNumber" id="selectPageNumber">
</select>
<select class="ctrl2" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" dojoAttachPoint="selectPageNumber2" id="selectPageNumber2">
</select>
```

widget:

```
alert(this.selectPageNumber);
alert(this.selectPageNumber2);
```

first alert shows that `this.selectPageNumber` is a valid object and the `this.selectPageNumber2` is null.
`widgetsInTemplate` is set to false.
all the code is within `dojo.addOnLoad()`
`dojo.require()` is valid
I am using IBM Rational Application Developer (if it is essential).

WHY it is so different?

Comment: I suggest putting together a standalone example the reproduces this exactly. You can put it on jsfiddle.net or something.

Comment: Did you add `this.inherited(arguments);` on postCreate and startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came close to the solution: it seems like there is a some sort of RAD "caching" that doesn't respond to changes made in html code.
[Ways to purge the workspace environment with RAD (based on Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299011/ways-to-purge-the-workspace-environment-with-rad-based-on-eclipse) might be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your syntax, I am assuming that you are using 1.6.  Your question mentions template and postCreate, so i am assuming that you have created a widget that acts as a composite (widgets in the template).

Assuming 1.6, in your widget, have you set the `widgetsInTemplate` property to true.  This will tell the parser that your template has widgets that need to be parsed when creating the widget.

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/templated/

I would remove the id from the select.  Having the id means that you can only instantiate your widget once per page.  You should use `this.selectPageNumber` within your widget to access the select widget.

If you are using 1.7 or greater, instead of setting the widgets `widgetsInTemplate` property, you should use the `dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin` mixin.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html

Comment: Id is ok, I instantiate it only once per page. And widgetsInTemplate: true doesn't help because it started to work with it set to false. But I got very interestig problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on when dijit.byId() is being called, the widget may not have been created yet. Try using dojo.addOnLoad()

```
 dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
     var select = dijit.byId("selectPageNumber");
 });
```

Comment: The problem has been solved without without dojo.addOnLoad, but the situation became too odd! Please check update on question.